# Bing search API limit and restricting to single page per domain

Tags: php, azure, search, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I've used Bing Search API 7-day trial (Guest) to get search results based on a term.

I'm using the same code as specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/quickstarts/php documentation.
I've added a foreach loop so that I can get the search result for each pages. For my search term I got API search result count **totalEstimatedMatches** as 38500000.

Below is my code:

```
function BingWebSearch ($url, $key, $query, $count="", $offset="") {
    $headers = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n";
    $options = array ('http' => array (
                          'header' => $headers,
                           'method' => 'GET'));

    // Perform the request and get a JSON response.
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $queryString = "?q=" . urlencode($query);
    if ( strlen(trim($count)) > 0 ) $queryString .= "&count=".$count;
    if ( strlen(trim($offset)) > 0 ) $queryString .= "&offset=".$offset;
    $result = file_get_contents($url . $queryString , false, $context);

    // Extract Bing HTTP headers.
    $headers = array();
    foreach ($http_response_header as $k => $v) {
        $h = explode(":", $v, 2);
        if (isset($h[1]))
            if (preg_match("/^BingAPIs-/", $h[0]) || preg_match("/^X-MSEdge-/", $h[0]))
                $headers[trim($h[0])] = trim($h[1]);
    }
    return array($headers, $result);
}

$accessKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$endpoint = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search';
$term = 'myserchterm';

$searchOffset = 0;
$offset = 0;
$totalEstimatedMatchesCount = 38500000;
$count = 5000;
for ( $searchCount=0; $searchCount <= $totalEstimatedMatchesCount; $searchCount = $searchCount+$searchOffset ) {
        $offset = $offset+$searchOffset;
        list($headers, $jsonPageResult) = BingWebSearch($endpoint, $accessKey, $term, $count, $offset);
        $bingSearchPageArray = json_decode($jsonPageResult);
        $searchOffset = count($bingSearchPageArray['webPages']['value']);
        // code to store result to database
        .....................................
}
```

This code gave only **930** results and I got email as

> You are approaching the quota limit on you subscription to the Bing
> SearchV7 - Free product. This quota will be renewed on 04/09/2020.
>
> Below are details on quota usage for the subscription:
>
> **Quota Scope**   **Calls**   **Call Quota**  **Bandwidth**   **Bandwidth Quota**
>
> Subscription       2.26k          3.00k            58.48MB

What is the maximum number of API calls I can make? How can I restrict the search only for webpages and only one page per domain(ie, I need to get index page only. I just need the domain based on my search, so no need of getting same domain pages again in the result)?

Can anyone help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

The Bing Search v7 API subscription covers several Bing Search services (Bing Image Search, Bing News Search, Bing Video Search, Bing Visual Search, and Bing Web Search), this pricing page explains the free limitations: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/

You can filter your search by topic (web pages, images, videos, news, etc.), using a request filter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/filter-answers

To limit your search to index pages only, try some of these advanced search prefixes you can add to your query: https://help.bing.microsoft.com/#apex/18/en-US/10001/-1